# Странное поведение python

Tags: python, память

```
from collections import deque
a = [[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7]]
a.append(a[-1])
a[-1][0] += 1
print(a)
```

Данный код выводит [[5, 5], [6, 6], [8, 7], [8, 7]], хотя я ожидаю [[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 7]].
Почему питон вместо создания новой ячейки памяти работает с ссылкой и как этого избежать?

Comment: Делать копию: `a.append(a[-1].copy())` или `a.append(a[-1][:])`

Comment: Спасибо. Я вот еще проверил, оказывается с Set такая же ситуация. Неужели все контейнеры с таким подвохом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вполне нормальное поведение изменяемых типов в python.
Конкретно в вашем примере достаточно использовать срез списка что бы избежать создания ссылки на тот же объект, и вместо этого создать новый объект.

```
a = [[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7]]
a.append(a[-1][:])
a[-1][0] += 1
# или
a.append(a[-1]*1)
# или
a.append(a[-1].copy())
print(a)
```

Так же у списков, словарей, множеств есть метод copy(), который создаёт копию объекта.